# Pythonic way to convert list of tuples to dict of lists?

Tags: python

Say I have a list of tuples:

```
[('M', 'Bob'), ('F', 'Jane'), ('F', 'Mary'), ('M', 'John'), ('M', 'Henry')]
```

I want to convert this to a dict of keys ('M' or 'F') containing lists of names:

```
{'M':['Bob', 'John', 'Henry'], 'F':['Jane', 'Mary']}
```

Is there any way to do this with a relatively simple comprehension? Clearly, I could initialize a dict containing empty lists for each key, and simply append names into the dict, but I thought there might be a more clever/readable way to do this.

Comment: Is this homework? I'm sure I saw an almost identical question in the last day or so.

Comment: You're never too old to learn!